# Idiomatic readable error handling in if-filters of for comprehensions with Futures

Tags: scala, error-handling, future, idioms, for-comprehension

I want to be able to distinguish between the instances of 'Future.filter predicate is not satisfied' error coming from separate lines, and fail with a specific error.

In other words, I want future f below to fail with a specific message:

```
 def condition1: Boolean = ???
 def condition2: Boolean = ???

 val f: Future[T] = for {
    _ <- (condition) orFail ("Condition 1 failed ")
    _ <- (condition) orFail ("Condition 2 failed ")
 } yield ???
```

orFail has been defined like so:

```
implicit class Blah(predicate: => Boolean) {
  def orFail ( s: String): Future[Unit] =
    if (predicate) Future( () ) else Future.failed(new Exception(s))
}
```

It does the job, but it also creates an extra Future object for any check. Is there a better way to do it without creating extra futures (perhaps by catching and re-throwing a specific error in each of those lines)?

Comment: Anyway you have to create a `Future` as you return a `Future`. If you don't want to have "calculation-in-another-thread" overhead, then `Future.successful(())` instead of `Future(())` will help, as it creates an already completed `Promise`

Comment: I thought of reusing the same Future object ...

Comment: if you think about `filter` `map` etc. on same future - the're actually creating new `Future` every time you call them